# Retrieving data from ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sql-update

I have a simple ajax call firing on click of a button, sending the element's id attribute via POST, No errors and the data is being sent, I checked on the network console.

Therefore the next logical step is to think it's an issue with the php, in which i'm making a simple update statement, the issue is the php can't see the data passed by the ajax call. please see below:

AJAX:

```
$("a.report_btn").click(function() {
    var url = "report_post.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("a.report_btn").attr("id"),
        success: function(response) {          
            content.html(response); 
            $(".liked_success").show();
        }, error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
    });
    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php include 'db_connect.php'; 

$id =$_POST['id'];

try {

    $sql = "UPDATE jobs_list
    SET post_like = post_like+1, TimeStamp = TimeStamp
    WHERE id=$id 
    LIMIT 1";

    $statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->bindValue("post_like", $_POST['post_like'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $count = $statement->execute();
    $dbh = null;        // Disconnect

}catch( PDOException $e ) {
    echo 'Ops... something went wrong...'; // error message
    var_dump($statement);
}

?>
```

Comment: there are no named placeholders in your query for one thing and checking for errors would have told you about it

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if the request is being made, and if so what the state of the response is along with any error codes?

Comment: The request was sent: Waiting (TTFB)

Comment: Don't believe me? Here, see for yourself http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: and the HTML is missing for all this

Comment: I'm surprised to see that none of my comments received an upvote.

Comment: Well I can't up vote it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- consider yourself served !

Comment: @Fred-ii- The request was sent, so I doubt the issue is with the html. I think the issue is with the php, but I'm a fart in a trance right now and can't see the mistake.

Comment: @bob what value did you really want to bind to `TimeStamp` ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I wanted the current TimeStamp already in the row.

Comment: @bob err ... i'm in a trance atm ... time to call it quits for the year for me ;)  your SQL and binding seem confusing. I would use different keywords for binding placeholders than the actual column names.

Comment: Happy new year whenever it is for you! Would that stop it working?